# How can I adapt this sqlite query so that it excludes PRODNAMEs that start with a lowercase x?

Tags: sql, sqlite, lowercase

```
SELECT t1.pgrpname, t1.pgrpval, t0.prodname 
FROM tproduct t0 inner join lpropgr l0 on l0.prodsern=t0.prodsern
INNER JOIN tpgroups t1 on t1.pgrsern=l0.pgrsern 
WHERE lower(t1.pgrpname) in ('brand', 'class1', 'display') 
ORDER BY t1.pgrpname collate nocase, t1.pgrpval collate nocase, t0.prodname collate nocase
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the answer was to change `in ('brand', 'class1', 'display')` for `in ('%@') and not('x' == substr(t0.prodname, 1, 1))` making the whole query:

```
SELECT t1.pgrpname, t1.pgrpval, t0.prodname 
FROM tproduct t0 
INNER JOIN lpropgr l0 on l0.prodsern=t0.prodsern 
INNER JOIN tpgroups t1 on t1.pgrsern=l0.pgrsern
WHERE lower(t1.pgrpname) in ('%@') 
AND NOT('x' == substr(t0.prodname, 1, 1)) 
ORDER BY t1.pgrpname collate nocase, t1.pgrpval collate nocase, t0.prodname collate nocase
```

Just for anybody reading who wanted to know.

Answer (score 0):

That SQL should do the work.

```
     SELECT t1.pgrpname, t1.pgrpval, t0.prodname 
       FROM tproduct t0 inner join lpropgr l0 on l0.prodsern=t0.prodsern
 INNER JOIN tpgroups t1 on t1.pgrsern=l0.pgrsern 
      WHERE lower(t1.pgrpname) in ('brand', 'class1', 'display') 
        AND lower(substr(t0.prodname,1)) != (substr(t0.prodname,1))
   ORDER BY t1.pgrpname collate nocase, t1.pgrpval collate nocase
```

Just compares first char of the column with lower version of char

Edit : Sorry missed the open parenthesis.

This one only checks for `lowercase x`

```
     SELECT t1.pgrpname, t1.pgrpval, t0.prodname 
       FROM tproduct t0 inner join lpropgr l0 on l0.prodsern=t0.prodsern
 INNER JOIN tpgroups t1 on t1.pgrsern=l0.pgrsern 
      WHERE lower(t1.pgrpname) in ('brand', 'class1', 'display') 
        AND lower(substr(t0.prodname,1)) != 'x'
   ORDER BY t1.pgrpname collate nocase, t1.pgrpval collate nocase
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Mahmut but that query won't run.  I'm not sure why.  It's also only lowercase x I want to exclude not all lowercase letters.

Comment: First one got problem with missed parenthesis. Also added second SQL just checks for `lowercase x`

Comment: Hi, that ran fine but return the same as my original query.  I'm not sure why as your code seems logical to me.

Comment: Because we forgot collate nocase in order by. Is your database NOCASE by default?

Comment: I don't think so.  As you can see I'm new to sqlite.  Well, never mind.  Thanks for trying

Comment: You are welcome. If it is NOCASE then you can run `PRAGMA case_sensitive_like=ON;` before calling the query and remove `COLLATE NOCASE`s from select.